# Local Broadcast Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, local, android-broadcast

dev.android mention that

> "you can also safely restrict the broadcast to a single application
>   with **Intent.setPackage**" ??

How does it differ from sending broadcast using **LocalBroadcast** ??

Comment: the same as "restrict to given(single) package" vs "restrict to your current app package(local) only"

Comment: Using LocalBroadcastManager, your application can only listen broadcast sent from same application.

But if you use setPackage, target application can listen broadcast from other application as well as same application.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalBroadcast` can only be received by the current app.

`setPackage` allows you to specify which app can receive the broadcast.